# function print in python shell

Tags: python

Can anyone explain me difference in python shell between output variable through "print" and when I just write variable name to output it?

```
>>> a = 5
>>> a
5
>>> print a
5
>>> b = 'some text'
>>> b
'some text'
>>> print b
some text
```

When I do this with text I understand difference but in int or float - I dont know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just entering an expression (such as a variable name) will actually output the representation of the result as returned by the `repr()` function, whereas `print` will convert the result to a string using the `str()` function.>>> s = "abc"

Printing `repr()` will give the same result as entering the expression directly:

```
>>> "abc"
'abc'
>>> print repr("abc")
'abc'
```

Answer (score 2):

Python's shell always returns the last value evaluated. When `a` is 5, it evaluates to 5, thus you see it. When you call `print`, `print` outputs the value (without quotes) and returns nothing, thus nothing gets produced after `print` is done. Thus, evaluating `b` results in `'some test'` and printing it just results in `some text`.