# Following the tensorflow document (version r0.11), I got a double print instead of single print

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Following the tensorflow document (version r0.11, Python 3.4.3), I got a wrong print with twice `1` instead of once `1`.

The code is following here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
state = tf.Variable(0, name="counter")
one = tf.constant(1)
new_value = tf.add(state, one)
update = tf.assign(state, new_value)
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  print(sess.run(state))
  for _ in range(3):
    sess.run(update)
    print(sess.run(state))
```

then the print result is like this

```
0
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you expect to see?

Comment: thank you, and I just want to print the 'state' one time.  And there is someone has already helped me to solve this question, but also thank you very much.

Comment: Thank Brian Tompsett for editing my question and correcting my spelling and grammar. I know my English is poor, and I'll try my best to describe the question clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sess.run(update)` update the variable **and** return its value. So when you run this code in a python shell, it print the value of `state` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350094/function-print-in-python-shell) why).

So if you want to see only one time each new value of `state`, remove 
 `print(sess.run(state))` or write your code in a python script.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. When I write the same code in one .py file and run the file, it gives result that I want. And then I do what you say, 'remove print(sess.run(state))' in the interactive model, it also shows the expected result. Thank you again!