# type() function doesn't work when used in a python script file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a program of two lines in python. At first I tested it in the python shell. Here it is:

```
>>>state=True
>>>type(state)
<class 'bool'>
```

The output was as I expected in the shell. 
And then I wrote these instructions in a file named main.py.

```
#---------------main.py----------------#
state=True
type(state)
```

Then I executed this program using linux terminal as root user. The output was nothing

```
[manjaro ~]# python main.py
[manjaro ~]#
```

I expected that the output would be as it was in the shell. As a beginner In python I don't know why there was no output. Please help me to understand why there was no output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [function print in python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350094/function-print-in-python-shell)

Comment: You can take a look at the answers in the dupe - together with KAsramds answer this should clairfy things. if not, ask by comment

Comment: The interactive shell is a Read–Eval–Print Loop. Printing is automatic in the shell. You may need to use the `print()` function in a Python script to display output. Advise you read the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) to learn the basics of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see is the raw representation of the object which is returned by `__repr__` method of the respective object. It's what is called when you type an object in Python's interactive shell. When you're in a file you need to print the result using `print` function that triggers the `__str__` method.

```
state=True
print(type(state))
```

Comment: can you please explain more about __repr__ method and __str__  please. I want to learn more about them from you. because unlike some awkard articles, You explained them clearly and neatly. Can you please tell more about them Please sir I request you! hope some help from you

Comment: @user9218974 Well, `__str__` and `__repr__` are not such complicated methods. The documentation has already explained their functionality clearly https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__. Please check the documentation and let me know if you had any further questions.